# WooCommerce pages looks unstyled

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm playing with woocommerce to customize the store aspect. I've noticed that If I open a product link, the page looks unstyled. I need to integrate the shop with my bootstrap 4 based theme. After reading the docs, I'm not sure how to proceed, this because it's written that the best way is to use the hooks. I want to use hooks and override the default templates, but inside the templates all the code is call the `do_action` function, amd there's only a bit of html markup. How I can customize the aspect with hooks and templating override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with woocommerce, there are two ways.

1 - Add some extra css to your current theme.

For example I want to modify the title of the product :

I open the chrome inspector, I see that the product page has a class css for `body.single-product`.

The product container has a class css `div.product` (create by woocommerce itself `<div id = "product - <? php the_ID ();?>" <? php wc_product_class ('', $ product);? >>`).

so, I can apply my own style, (for example my theme displays the title in an `h1` tag of css class `product-title`)

So ; i cann override by :

```
body.single.single-product div.product h1.product-title {
  color: #13345f;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

and so for the other elements in my product page.

2 - Second method, and that you create your own templates: `your-theme/woocomerce /` , and use `wc_get_template_part()` .

For example : I want to create a custom product details .

In my theme, I create the folder woocomerce, and a template named `single-produt.php`, and in the same level a template named `content-single-product-custom.php` .

and inside `single-produt.php` , i call it by : `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom' );`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have two more question about, I will use the templating option because I want to customize at all the layout. When I call the `wc_get_template_part` function I need to be inside a loop right and I need to create first the php templates right? Also for the templates, I saw that they are using hook, I need also to modify them or the templates overriding will work fine ?

Comment: yes. for the hooks `do_action` you can overwrite theme by `add_filter` . here you can find a [full List and Examples](https://premmerce.com/woocommerce-hooks-guide/)

Comment: I can also remove the `do_action` and use loops and pure markup?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: the function only calls the components to mount the Product page, you can: remove, modify each part of the product page .

`function custom_woocommerce_before_cart(){ // Your Custom content}`

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_woocommerce_before_cart', 10, 1 ); `